# C++17: How to determine whether a class template is "more specialized"

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

### Background

I'm trying to understand what Raymond Chen does in [his article about deconstructing function pointer templates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200713-00/?p=103978). He constructs what he says is a class template partial specialization like so:

```
template<typename F> struct FunctionTraits;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct FunctionTraits<R(*)(Args...)>
{
...
};
```

I was very weirded out by the fact that the "specialization" suddenly has more parameters than the primary class template. That is supposed to be valid? So I tried a deep dive into the relevant parts of the C++17 standard, which I don't understand.

- Section 14.5.5.8 (`[temp.class.spec]`)  says:

> Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization, the following restrictions apply:
> …
>
> - The specialization shall be more specialized than the primary template (14.5.5.2).

### What does 'more specialized' mean?

Here's my best attempt at understanding:

---

Section 14.5.5.2 (`[temp.class.order]`) says that `template< Foo > class X < Foo > {};` is *more specialized* than `template< Bar > class X<Bar>` iff `template< Foo > void f(X<Foo>);` is more specialized than `template< Bar > void f(X<Bar>);` - i.e., it delegates the specification of *more specialized* to function template specialization in 14.5.6.2. Note that here, `Foo` and `Bar` do not mean types, but rather any valid string describing template parameters.

---

Section 14.5.6.2 (`[temp.func.order]`) describes function template specialization ordering as a two-step process: First, apply a transformation, then perform template argument deduction. Template argument deduction (14.8.2.4) then specifies what is *more specialized*. I don't understand the described transformation. The standard says:

> […] for each type, non-type, or template template parameter (including template parameter packs (14.5.3) thereof) synthesize a unique type, value, or class template respectively and substitute it for each occurrence of that parameter in the function type of the template. […]

The rest of that paragraph is only about `cv`-qualifiers and member functions, which should be irrelevant for our case. The way I understand this procedure is: Given a function template like

```
template<class T> void my_func(T t);
```

the compiler "synthesizes" (i.e., "creates"?) a new dummy type, call it `struct MyFuncDummyType {};` and replaces above template declaration with a declaration where each `T` has been substituted with `MyFuncDummyType`:

```
template<class T>
void my_func(MyFuncDummyType t);
```

or, depending on how to interprete "substitute if for each occurence of that parameter in the function type":

```
void my_func(MyFuncDummyType t);
```

In the latter case, we don't have a template anymore, and template argument deduction can't happen, so I assume the former. However, now the function is not dependent on `T` anymore, so we can clearly not deduce any template arguments *for the transformed templates*. Let's see what 14.8.2.4 says how the deduction *for the original template* is supposed to happen.

---

Section 14.8.2.4 (`[temp.deduct.partial]`) explains how two function template (partial specializations) are to be compared based on the above transformation.

I'll try to explain my understanding using an example. Say we have `(A)` as `template<class T, int I> void func(T t);` and `(B)` as `template<class T> void func<T, 42>(T t);`. Following my logic above, the transformed `(A)` (let's call it `(A')`) should look like `template<class T, int I> void func<SomeDummyClass, SomeInteger>(SomeDummyClass t);` (replace `T` and `I` with some single-use dummy type/value) and `(B')` should be `template<class T> void func<SomeOtherDummyClass, 42>(SomeOtherDummyClass t);`.

The standard now says:

> The deduction process uses the transformed type as the argument template and the original type of the other template as the parameter template.

Unfortunately, I can not find out what `argument template` and `parameter template` is supposed to mean. These terms do not appear in the standard before this use. It goes on:

> This process is done twice for each type involved in the partial ordering comparison: once using the transformed template-1 as the argument template and template-2 as the parameter template and again using the transformed template-2 as the argument template and template-1 as the parameter template.

My best guess here is that "using the transformed template-1 as the argument template and template-2 as the parameter template" means to combine the `template<…>` part (apparently called the "parameter template"?) from "template-2" (`(B)` in our case) and the `func<…>` part (this then being the "argument template"?) from the transformed "template-1" (i.e., `(A')`). This would yield:

```
template<class T>      // from (B)
void func<SomeDummyClass, SomeInteger>(SomeDummyClass t);  // from (A')
```

and vice versa as:

```
template<class T, int I>  // from (A)
void func<SomeOtherDummyClass, 42>(SomeOtherDummyClass t); // from (B')
```

The latter seems broken, since `I` is a template parameter as well as specialized to `42`. This is the point where I have to give up. Some of my assumptions must be wrong (and make it impossible to parse the further description of the process in the standard), but I can't figure out which.

Comment: "*two function template (partial specializations)*" Function templates cannot be *partially* specialized. You can overload template functions, but that's a different thing from partial specialization.

Comment: I suggest not not dig deep into the standard for answers, and instead to read some tutorials (or your C++ book chapters) on template specialization. A specialization having different template parameters compared to the primary template is not unusual, and can be explained without language-lawyering.

Comment: “Parameter” and “argument” refer to the roles of parameters and arguments in template argument deduction for a function call: the parameter has the dependent types, while the argument supplies values for the template parameters in them.

Comment: About "more parameters" part, a simplified example: `template <typename T> struct S{};` then you can define specialization for `map<Key,Value>` type as: `template <typename K, typename V> struct S<std::map<K, V>> {};`, so `S<std::map<int, int>> x;` would instanciate the specialization. nothing wrong or unexpected here.